# Google calendar API keep account connected

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

I am new with the Google calendar API (PHP / MySQL and codeigniter 3).
I want to set up a two-way synchronization of my calendar.

I manage to authorize the recovery of events, also to modify them, delete them and add new ones.

But after a while my token_access is no longer valid.
How to do so that my application does not need to reconnect the Google account at each launch? I think I have not understood very well how this rule works.

I am based on this tutorial https://techarise.com/integrate-google-calendar-api-with-codeigniter-calendar-library/

If you could enlighten me on this subject?

A big thank-you

Comment: Hello demenvil, please show us some code!

Comment: Hi, my code is identical to https://techarise.com/integrate-google-calendar-api-with-codeigniter-calendar-library/

Comment: Yes, but what is the exact error message your are getting? On which part of the code the error is thrown? What have you tried before to solve your issue?

Comment: I have no errors
Just that my google account is no longer connected after a while so I lose access to the calendar.
I have to go through the consent screen again
I don't understand how I can get access to calendars all the time
mine and those of my users

Comment: Can you try the official quickstart example for PHP provided by Google and check if it shows the same behavior? https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But after a while my token_access is no longer valid.

This is normal and there is no way to prevent you from connecting to google to get your credentials.

What you actually would need to do is to [refresh your token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) so you don't need to get a whole new `Authorization code`.

If you want a more detailed explanation to understand how the OAuth2 workflow works in google I would recommend you to read [this page from the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). And if you want to read the whole [RFC of OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) you can do it as well.

Although I would strongly recommend using and testing in [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) to see what are the actual HTTP request you need to make in order to refresh tokens.

---

**TL;DR:** Access token expires after its creation and this is expected. You need to use the refresh token to get a new access token.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
This allowed me to write this working code!
Regardless of the computer or mobile client, my account is automatically connected without having to go through the consent screen.
And bi-directional synchronization is done correctly.
A big thank you to you

```
  public function getClientGoogle(){
      if($this->dataUserCal->google_calendar == 'Oui'){
        if ($this->googleapi->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $this->googleapi->setAccessToken(json_decode($this->dataUserCal->data_token_google,true));
  $r = $this->googleapi->getRefreshToken();
      $token =  $this->googleapi->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->googleapi->getRefreshToken());
    $this->tokenAccessGoogle = $token['access_token'];
            $this->db->set('access_key_google', $token['access_token']);
            $this->db->set('data_token_google', json_encode($token));
          $this->db->set('date_access_key_google',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $this->db->where('id', $this->session->userdata('id_user'));
    $this->db->update('users');
        } else {
         $this->tokenAccessGoogle = $this->dataUserCal->access_key_google;
        }
      }

        }
```